# view.setTag(Object obj) throws nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to create an app with **listview and arrayadapter**.
I have a custom class(Word) and a custom adapter(WordAdapter).
By running this code, the **app is crashing** 
this is the **error :**

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.view.View.setTag(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Code given below :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {

    //datastructure to hold two textviews, so that it can be reused rather than instantiating
    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView1;
        TextView textView2;
    }

    //sets up the arrayadapter
    //@param context : specify the context (e.g current activity)
    //@param words : list of words to populate the view (contains objects of custom word class)
    public WordAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull ArrayList<Word> words) {
        super(context, 0, words);
    }

    /*
    Needs to override when using custom arrayadapater.
    Called by the adapter class when populating data from data source into the view
    @param position : position of the data in the data source
    @param convertView : data from source is set as the data for this view
    @param parent : parent view to which convertview gets attached
     */
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        View list_item_view = convertView;

        //checks if any reusable view is available
        //list_item_view = null if no reusable view is available
        if (list_item_view == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            //convert the custom layout file into view object and inflate the parent with the view
            //returns the root of the custom layout file (if attachToRoot = false)
            //returns parent view to which the layout is to be attached (if attachToRoot = true)
            list_item_view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

            viewHolder.textView1 = (TextView) list_item_view.findViewById(R.id.miwok_text_view);
            viewHolder.textView2 = (TextView) list_item_view.findViewById(R.id.default_text_view);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //get the data from the position
        Word word = getItem(position);

        //set the miwok word
        viewHolder.textView1.setText(word.getMiwokWord());

        //set the default word
        viewHolder.textView2.setText(word.getDefaultWord());

        //retrun the view to which data is to be placed
        return list_item_view;
    }

}
```

Anyone please help.

Comment: remove `list_item_view` and use `convertView` only.

Comment: thanks @SandipSoni it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change the following lines:

```
 list_item_view .setTag(viewHolder);

 viewHolder = (ViewHolder) list_item_view .getTag();
```